# How To Resolve the Error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string

Tags: wordpress, error-handling

I am working on media upload to database with Ajax through the Following Function:

```
function addCustomer(){

global $wpdb;

/*require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );*/

$user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
$member_name = $_POST["member_name"];
$member_title = $_POST["member_title"];
$member_email = $_POST["member_email"];
$member_twitter_url = $_POST["member_twitter_url"];
$member_linkden_url = $_POST["member_linkden_url"];
$member_image333 = $_POST["member_image"];
$myText = (string)$member_image333;
echo $member_image_id  = media_handle_upload('member_image', $myText);
die();
if($wpdb->insert(
  'gloriac_company_team',
   $test[] = array(
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'member_name' => $member_name,
    'member_title' => $member_title,
    'member_email' => $member_email,
    'member_twitter_url' => $member_twitter_url,
    'member_linkedin_url' => $member_linkden_url,
    'member_image' => $member_image_id,
    'member_reg_date' => current_time( 'mysql' )
  )

)===FALSE){

echo "Error";

}
```

But when i submit the form and action comes to this function its not uploaded the media to word press as well as its not storing the image ID to the database as it generates an error for me as follows:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted
>   to string in
>   /home/mxcounte/public_html/gorilla-crowd/wp-content/themes/Impreza-child/functions.php
>   on line 230

I have tried to convert the Integer output to string as follows but still there is no luck can anyone help in fixing this issue.

```
$myText = (string)$member_image333;
```

Comment: Are you inserting it to correct table.

Comment: I think file should be handle with `$_FILES`, you are using `$_POST`

Comment: yes i am adding to correct table @Waqas_aamer

Comment: this one: echo $member_image_id  = media_handle_upload('member_image', $myText); @Waqas_aamer

Comment: i have tried it with $_FILES but still the same error @Milap

Comment: first remove echo from it

Comment: then check whether something is coming to it or not by this.

Comment: echo "<pre>";var_dump($member_image_id);

Comment: let me try this. but right now echo is returns a string to me.. @Waqas_aamer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108825/discussion-between-xabby-and-waqas-aamer).

Answer (score -1):

First remove echo from this. then check whether something is coming to it or not by
echo "";var_dump($member_image_id);

If data is coming then check whether you have done this correctly or not
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload